# Methods that do return a value ones that make change to the orignal data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

After I learned about different data types I learned that once an object from a given type is created it has innate methods that can do 'things'.
Playing around, I noticed that, while some methods return a value, others make change to the original data stored.

Is there any specific term for these two types of methods and is there any intuition or logic as to which methods return a value and which make changes?

For example:

```
abc= "something"

defg= [12,34,11,45,132,1]

abc.capitalise()   #this returns a value

defg.sort()        #this changes the orignal list
```

Comment: Virtually all methods on strings return new objects, because strings are *immutable*. Lists are *mutable*, so many of their methods can return `None` and mutate the instance instead.

Comment: Aha, so I overlooked the nature of the datatype.That essentially plays a vital role in what can/can't be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any specific term for these two types of methods

A method that changes an object's state (ie `list.sort()`) is usually called a "mutator" (it "mutates" the object). There's no general name for methods that return values - they could be "getters" (methods that take no arguments and return part of the object's state), alternative constructors (methods that are called on the class itself and provide an alternative way to construct an instance of the class), or just methods that take some arguments, do some computations based on both the arguments and the object's state and return a result, or actually just do anything (do some computation AND change the object's state AND return a value).

> is there any intuition or logic as to which methods return a value and which make changes?

Some Python objects are immutable (strings, numerics, tuples etc) so when you're working on one of those types you know you won't have any mutator. Except for this special case, nope, you will have to check the doc. The only naming convention here is that methods whose name starts with "set_" and take one argument will change the object's state based on their argument (and most often return nothing) and that methods whose name starts with "get_" and take no arguments will return informations on the object's state and change nothing (you'll often see the formers named "setters" and the laters named "getters"), but like any convention it's only followed by those who follow it, IOW don't assume that because a method name starts with "get_" or "set_" it will indeed behave as expected.

Comment: Great.Thanks a lot. Sorry I can't upvote given my current rep

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so all libraries that do string manipulation will return a new string.

For the other types, you will have to refer to the library documentation.